# aggfunc to get an arbitrary value in cells of a pandas pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I'd like to use `pivot_table` to show an arbitrary value of a column in each cell. For example, given a `DataFrame` like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['x1', 'x1', 'x2'],
                   'y': ['a', 'b', 'c']})
```

To count the values of `y` for each value of `x`:

```
df.pivot_table(index='x', values='y', aggfunc=len)
    y
x   
x1  2
x2  1
```

So in place of `[2, 1]`, I'd like to get `['a', 'c']` or `['b', 'c']`.

I tried these approaches, but all produce errors ([notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1J-MvZJLrzfIsB5G-e2cA9-DH6T4Q4Z7w#scrollTo=FMr5yTZdS5hO)):

```
df.pivot_table(index='x', values='y', aggfunc=sample)
df.pivot_table(index='x', values='y', aggfunc=head)
df.pivot_table(index='x', values='y', aggfunc=lambda x: x[0])
```

Per https://stackoverflow.com/a/38982172/1840471, an alternative is using `groupby` and `agg`, and this produces the desired result in this case:

```
df.groupby(['x']).y.agg('head')
```

However, I'm looking to use `pivot_table` because my full use case involves getting values in rows and columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `first` as follows:

```
df.pivot_table(index='x', values='y', aggfunc='first')

Out[67]:
    y
x
x1  a
x2  c
```